# Get row of a checkbox inside a listview wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, checkbox

I'm new on this thing and I have a problem that after some research I coouldn't find any answer that worked...
I have this XAML code:

```
<ListView Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="EpisodesList">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Season" Width="Auto">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Season}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Episode" Width="50">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Episode}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Assitido" Width="50">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Watched}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Baixar" Width="50">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Download}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

And this behind the XAML:

```
public SerieInfo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<Episodes> episodes = new List<Episodes>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            episodes.Add(new Episodes()
            {
                Season = i.ToString(),
                Episode = (i + 2).ToString(),
                Download = true,
                Watched = true,
            });
        }
        EpisodesList.ItemsSource = episodes;

    }


    public class Episodes
    {
        public string Season { get; set; }
        public string Episode { get; set; }
        public bool Download { get; set; }
        public bool Watched { get; set; }

    }
```

When any of the checkboxes get unchecked or checked I'll need to get the season value of that row for example...

```
+--------+---------+---------+----------+
| Season | Episode | Watched | Download |
+--------+---------+---------+----------+
| 1      |   3     | Checked |Unchecked | <-- Get the "1" value when any checkbox change
+--------+---------+---------+----------+
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the checkbox's checked and unchecked event to get the season. Refer to the code below.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<Episodes> episodes = new List<Episodes>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            episodes.Add(new Episodes()
            {
                Season = i.ToString(),
                Episode = (i + 2).ToString(),
                Download = true,
                Watched = true,
            });
        }
        EpisodesList.ItemsSource = episodes;
    }

    private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chk = sender as CheckBox;
        Episodes epi = chk.DataContext as Episodes;
        var season = epi.Season;
    }

    private void CheckBox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chk = sender as CheckBox;
        Episodes epi = chk.DataContext as Episodes;
        var season = epi.Season;
    }
}
```

and the XAML

```
 <ListView Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="EpisodesList">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Season" Width="Auto">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Season}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Episode" Width="50">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Episode}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Assitido" Width="50">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Watched}" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Baixar" Width="50">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Download}" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```